# How to bind F1 key in the new Foobar2000 release?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, keyboard-shortcuts, foobar2000

In the latest version of Foobar2000 I can't bind <kbd>F1</kbd> to nothing since, when I press it, it opens the help screen.

I could do it in previous versions...

Comment: I can still do it - http://www.screencast.com/users/SathyaBhat/folders/Snagit/media/ab3250c8-24a1-4fa5-9cad-868a9f2d004f

Comment: @Sathya you are using `v1.0.1`, I am talking about `v1.1`

Comment: @Jader I just upgraded to v1.1, and it still works, although it's not a global hotkey.

Comment: @Sathya okay, it imported the settings from the previous version. What about a fresh install?

Comment: @Jader Good point, I'll try to doing a fresh install in a VM

Comment: crossposted on Foobar2000 forum http://www.hydrogenaudio.org/forums/index.php?showtopic=85788

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The <kbd>F1</kbd> key cannot be currently bound. The key press is eaten by the dialog to do the action associated with the questionmark button in the top-right corner.

Source: [hydrogenaudio.org](http://www.hydrogenaudio.org/forums/index.php?showtopic=83299)

You can consider this as official since Yirkha is a long-time FB2K Moderator and plugin developer.
Sorry for that news :-/

Answer (score 1):

Binding to <kbd>F1</kbd> works in fb2k v1.0.1. Install the old version (found it at http://www.filehippo.com/download_foobar2000/7165/), set hotkeys, then install 1.1+ – your previous association gets imported.